# How can I set the range of the first listobject in an Excel worksheet to be a variable?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro in Excel that I use to alter and process data in a table. I'm trying to make it less specific in the table that it affects. When I need to search through the table, my macro explicitly references the table name and sometimes the specific table header like so:

`Range("productUpdate[id]")`

I want my macro to be able to handle table's that do not match that specific criteria. I figured I could assign the name to a variable, but I don't know to get the data I need. How would I accomplish this?

My criteria for finding the information:

- The table's name could be anything.
- The first column header could be named anything.
- The table is always going to be the first table/listobject in the worksheet.

Comment: Please do not use the [**macros** tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info) for MS Office / VBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming I understand your question correctly, you can refer point a variable to the first table in the worksheet as such:

```
Sub Testit()
    Dim tbl As ListObject

    Set tbl = Sheet1.ListObjects(1)
End Sub
```

From there, you can reference the tables properties as needed. Examples follow:

```
MsgBox tbl.Name
MsgBox tbl.ListColumns.Count
MsgBox tbl.ListColumns(2).Name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use string concatenation. `Range(tblN & "[" & colN & "]")` where `tblN` and `colN` are string variables with the table name and column name.

Comment: Would it be possible to set that code as a variable? I tried ``myRange = Range(tblN & "[" & colN & "]")`` but it didn't work. Also, what is the most efficient way to get the ``tblN`` and ``colN``?